# Double circular reference in PHP

Tags: php, html, excel, iteration, circular-reference

Does anybody know if a double circular reference is supported in php? A single circular reference conversion from excel to php works absolutely fine, but when i add a second circular reference it does not seem to work anymore in php (I don't have any problems in excel).

Would be great if anybody could help me with this.

Thx